# jQuery Mobile, reload Dom after submit

Tags: forms, wordpress, dom, jquery, jquery-mobile

I try to develop a theme for WordPress with jQuery Mobile.

But I have a problem with comments. Comments are generated by WordPress as *http://www.foo.bar/2012/03/post/#comment-62*

Problem is the hastag (#) in Url, jQuery Mobie dislikes, I believe. :)

So far, I use following syntax, and my scripts work well...

```
jQuery('#page').live('pageinit', function() {
    jQuery.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

I tried to apply *data-ajax = "false"* to my form, without result. Finally, I tried...

```
jQuery('#page').live('pageinit', function() {
    jQuery.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $('#commentform').bind('submit', function() {
    jQuery.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
    });
});
```

When my page reloads, my scripts are broken!

Any idea or advice would be greatly appreciate. :) I'm a beginner.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You can specify JQM configuration in the `mobileinit` event. But this will disable ajax throughout.

```
$('document').bind('mobileinit', function () {
    console.log("mobile init");
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
}).trigger('mobileinit');

//...

$('document').ready(function () {
   // ...
});
```

Or you can add `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag without disabling ajax throughout.

```
<form data-ajax="false">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I had tried with data-ajax = false. With "trigger", I get an error loading the page.